# how can I pause and then resume a call to `sleep`

Tags: c, linux, bash, time, sleep

Calling `sleep(10)` means to sleep for the specified number of seconds. When I type "sleep 10" I suppose to wait 10 seconds but when I'm using CTRL-Z (or sending `SIGTSTP`) right after sleep command, it won't stop the "timer" (or the counter) even though that the process has stopped.

I can see via `jobs` that the status of `sleep` has changed to `STOPPED` but if I'll wait 10 seconds and then send this process to the foreground it will **finish immediately**, even though it run less then 10 seconds.

So, my question is how can I stop sleep timer from running??

**Update**:: I Understand now that sleep is using wall-clock time, so how can I implement sleep with a user cpu time

Comment: My suspicion is that once you restart `sleep`, it immediately notices that more than 10 seconds have passed since it was originally called, and so 'job done!'

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl-C instead of Ctrl-Z?

Comment: `sleep` uses real/wall time not CPU time. You can implement a CPU time based sleep using an interval timer with a type of `ITIMER_VIRTUAL`. See [set_itimer](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer) for more details.

Comment: The end of the sleep is in "wall clock" time, not "process" time, since the process will not be running. Suspending the process does not stop the wall clock's progress.

Comment: @kaylum. Thanks, I undersand now what was my mistake

Comment: @Matt.St, your question seems a bit confusing and self-contradicting... Are you trying to interrupt sleep before it's done... sleeping?

Comment: @InnocentBystander. Exactly. how can i change the question to be lesss confusing

Comment: @Matt.St, my understanding is you want your process to sleep for 10s regardless of any pauses, etc. Correct? What language? c or bash? (you have both tags)

Comment: @InnocentBystander, I mean that when i send stop signal to sleep 30, it wont stop the timer, so even if i send a stop signal. and after 40 seconds i send the sleep process o fg it wont run

Comment: @kaylum `ITIMER_VIRTUAL` has the same problem as `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I'm using C and using exec to call "Sleep" with bash, it doesn't matter if I send it to bg/fg as long as I send SIGCONT to the sleep process

Comment: @InnocentBystander Seriously, I had no difficulty figuring out what the OP meant - a program *written* in C, but interrupted from Bash.
Actually writing the code took a little longer because I wanted to do interesting stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sleep(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) returns the number of seconds remaining if it was interrupted by a signal, but seconds are poor granularity, so it's better to use [`clock_nanosleep(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_nanosleep).

`clock_nanosleep` also has the advantage of allowing you to specify what kind of clock you want to sleep with - there are at least 7 different clocks, each useful in different circumstances. Chances are you want `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` though. (Note that you use *no* CPU time while sleeping, so you definitely don't want `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` (it would be meaningful in a multithreaded process))

Quoting the latter man page:

```
   If the call is interrupted by a signal handler, clock_nanosleep() fails
   with the error EINTR.  In addition, if remain is not  NULL,  and  flags
   was not TIMER_ABSTIME, it returns the remaining unslept time in remain.
   This value can then be used to call clock_nanosleep()  again  and  com‐
   plete a (relative) sleep.
```

Edit: I ended up writing a program demonstrating what you need to do, as well as the difference between the various clocks:

```
/*
    Requires adding
        -pthread -lrt
    to your command line.
 */
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L

#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

struct all_times
{
    struct timespec realtime;

#ifdef CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE
    struct timespec realtime_coarse;
#endif

    struct timespec monotonic;

#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE
    struct timespec monotonic_coarse;
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW
    struct timespec monotonic_raw;
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_BOOTTIME
    struct timespec boottime;
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID
    struct timespec process_cputime_id;
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID
    struct timespec thread_cputime_id;
#endif

    struct timespec clock_getcpuclockid;

    struct timespec pthread_getcpuclockid;
};

void get_all_times(struct all_times *times)
{
    clockid_t clock;
    struct timespec *spec;

    memset(times, '\0', sizeof(*times));

    clock = CLOCK_REALTIME;
    spec = &times->realtime;
    clock_gettime(clock, spec);

#ifdef CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE
    clock = CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE;
    spec = &times->realtime_coarse;
    clock_gettime(clock, spec);
#endif

    clock = CLOCK_MONOTONIC;
    spec = &times->monotonic;
    clock_gettime(clock, spec);

#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE
    clock = CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE;
    spec = &times->monotonic_coarse;
    clock_gettime(clock, spec);
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW
    clock = CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW;
    spec = &times->monotonic_raw;
    clock_gettime(clock, spec);
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_BOOTTIME
    clock = CLOCK_BOOTTIME;
    spec = &times->boottime;
    clock_gettime(clock, spec);
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID
    clock = CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID;
    spec = &times->process_cputime_id;
    clock_gettime(clock, spec);
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID
    clock = CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID;
    spec = &times->thread_cputime_id;
    clock_gettime(clock, spec);
#endif

    clock_getcpuclockid(0, &clock);
    spec = &times->clock_getcpuclockid;
    clock_gettime(clock, spec);

    pthread_getcpuclockid(pthread_self(), &clock);
    spec = &times->pthread_getcpuclockid;
    clock_gettime(clock, spec);
}

void get_all_res(struct all_times *times)
{
    clockid_t clock;
    struct timespec *spec;

    memset(times, '\0', sizeof(*times));

    clock = CLOCK_REALTIME;
    spec = &times->realtime;
    clock_getres(clock, spec);

#ifdef CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE
    clock = CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE;
    spec = &times->realtime_coarse;
    clock_getres(clock, spec);
#endif

    clock = CLOCK_MONOTONIC;
    spec = &times->monotonic;
    clock_getres(clock, spec);

#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE
    clock = CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE;
    spec = &times->monotonic_coarse;
    clock_getres(clock, spec);
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW
    clock = CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW;
    spec = &times->monotonic_raw;
    clock_getres(clock, spec);
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_BOOTTIME
    clock = CLOCK_BOOTTIME;
    spec = &times->boottime;
    clock_getres(clock, spec);
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID
    clock = CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID;
    spec = &times->process_cputime_id;
    clock_getres(clock, spec);
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID
    clock = CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID;
    spec = &times->thread_cputime_id;
    clock_getres(clock, spec);
#endif

    clock_getcpuclockid(0, &clock);
    spec = &times->clock_getcpuclockid;
    clock_getres(clock, spec);

    pthread_getcpuclockid(pthread_self(), &clock);
    spec = &times->pthread_getcpuclockid;
    clock_getres(clock, spec);
}

void diff_time(const struct timespec *start, const struct timespec *end, struct timespec *diff)
{
    diff->tv_sec = end->tv_sec - start->tv_sec;
    diff->tv_nsec = end->tv_nsec - start->tv_nsec;
    if (diff->tv_nsec < 0)
    {
        diff->tv_nsec += 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
        diff->tv_sec--;
    }
    assert (diff->tv_sec >= 0);
    assert (diff->tv_nsec >= 0);
}

void diff_all_times(const struct all_times *start, const struct all_times *end, struct all_times *diff)
{
    diff_time(&start->realtime, &end->realtime, &diff->realtime);
    diff_time(&start->realtime, &end->realtime, &diff->realtime);

#ifdef CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE
    diff_time(&start->realtime_coarse, &end->realtime_coarse, &diff->realtime_coarse);
#endif

    diff_time(&start->monotonic, &end->monotonic, &diff->monotonic);

#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE
    diff_time(&start->monotonic_coarse, &end->monotonic_coarse, &diff->monotonic_coarse);
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW
    diff_time(&start->monotonic_raw, &end->monotonic_raw, &diff->monotonic_raw);
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_BOOTTIME
    diff_time(&start->boottime, &end->boottime, &diff->boottime);
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID
    diff_time(&start->process_cputime_id, &end->process_cputime_id, &diff->process_cputime_id);
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID
    diff_time(&start->thread_cputime_id, &end->thread_cputime_id, &diff->thread_cputime_id);
#endif

    diff_time(&start->clock_getcpuclockid, &end->clock_getcpuclockid, &diff->clock_getcpuclockid);

    diff_time(&start->pthread_getcpuclockid, &end->pthread_getcpuclockid, &diff->pthread_getcpuclockid);
}

void print_all_times(const struct all_times *start, const struct all_times *end, const struct all_times *diff, const struct all_times *res)
{
    printf("%-27s %15s %-9s %15s %-9s %5s %-9s %5s %-9s\n", "clock", "", "start", "", "end", "", "diff", "", "res");

    printf("%-27s %15lld.%09ld %15lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld\n", "CLOCK_REALTIME", (long long)start->realtime.tv_sec, start->realtime.tv_nsec, (long long)end->realtime.tv_sec, end->realtime.tv_nsec, (long long)diff->realtime.tv_sec, diff->realtime.tv_nsec, (long long)res->realtime.tv_sec, res->realtime.tv_nsec);

    printf("%-27s %15lld.%09ld %15lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld\n", "CLOCK_REALTIME", (long long)start->realtime.tv_sec, start->realtime.tv_nsec, (long long)end->realtime.tv_sec, end->realtime.tv_nsec, (long long)diff->realtime.tv_sec, diff->realtime.tv_nsec, (long long)res->realtime.tv_sec, res->realtime.tv_nsec);

#ifdef CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE
    printf("%-27s %15lld.%09ld %15lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld\n", "CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE", (long long)start->realtime_coarse.tv_sec, start->realtime_coarse.tv_nsec, (long long)end->realtime_coarse.tv_sec, end->realtime_coarse.tv_nsec, (long long)diff->realtime_coarse.tv_sec, diff->realtime_coarse.tv_nsec, (long long)res->realtime_coarse.tv_sec, res->realtime_coarse.tv_nsec);
#else
    printf("%-27s (not available)\n", "CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE");
#endif

    printf("%-27s %15lld.%09ld %15lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld\n", "CLOCK_MONOTONIC", (long long)start->monotonic.tv_sec, start->monotonic.tv_nsec, (long long)end->monotonic.tv_sec, end->monotonic.tv_nsec, (long long)diff->monotonic.tv_sec, diff->monotonic.tv_nsec, (long long)res->monotonic.tv_sec, res->monotonic.tv_nsec);

#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE
    printf("%-27s %15lld.%09ld %15lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld\n", "CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE", (long long)start->monotonic_coarse.tv_sec, start->monotonic_coarse.tv_nsec, (long long)end->monotonic_coarse.tv_sec, end->monotonic_coarse.tv_nsec, (long long)diff->monotonic_coarse.tv_sec, diff->monotonic_coarse.tv_nsec, (long long)res->monotonic_coarse.tv_sec, res->monotonic_coarse.tv_nsec);
#else
    printf("%-27s (not available)\n", "CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE");
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW
    printf("%-27s %15lld.%09ld %15lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld\n", "CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW", (long long)start->monotonic_raw.tv_sec, start->monotonic_raw.tv_nsec, (long long)end->monotonic_raw.tv_sec, end->monotonic_raw.tv_nsec, (long long)diff->monotonic_raw.tv_sec, diff->monotonic_raw.tv_nsec, (long long)res->monotonic_raw.tv_sec, res->monotonic_raw.tv_nsec);
#else
    printf("%-27s (not available)\n", "CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW");
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_BOOTTIME
    printf("%-27s %15lld.%09ld %15lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld\n", "CLOCK_BOOTTIME", (long long)start->boottime.tv_sec, start->boottime.tv_nsec, (long long)end->boottime.tv_sec, end->boottime.tv_nsec, (long long)diff->boottime.tv_sec, diff->boottime.tv_nsec, (long long)res->boottime.tv_sec, res->boottime.tv_nsec);
#else
    printf("%-27s (not available)\n", "CLOCK_BOOTTIME");
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID
    printf("%-27s %15lld.%09ld %15lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld\n", "CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID", (long long)start->process_cputime_id.tv_sec, start->process_cputime_id.tv_nsec, (long long)end->process_cputime_id.tv_sec, end->process_cputime_id.tv_nsec, (long long)diff->process_cputime_id.tv_sec, diff->process_cputime_id.tv_nsec, (long long)res->process_cputime_id.tv_sec, res->process_cputime_id.tv_nsec);
#else
    printf("%-27s (not available)\n", "CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID");
#endif

#ifdef CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID
    printf("%-27s %15lld.%09ld %15lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld\n", "CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID", (long long)start->thread_cputime_id.tv_sec, start->thread_cputime_id.tv_nsec, (long long)end->thread_cputime_id.tv_sec, end->thread_cputime_id.tv_nsec, (long long)diff->thread_cputime_id.tv_sec, diff->thread_cputime_id.tv_nsec, (long long)res->thread_cputime_id.tv_sec, res->thread_cputime_id.tv_nsec);
#else
    printf("%-27s (not available)\n", "CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID");
#endif

    printf("%-27s %15lld.%09ld %15lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld\n", "clock_getcpuclockid", (long long)start->clock_getcpuclockid.tv_sec, start->clock_getcpuclockid.tv_nsec, (long long)end->clock_getcpuclockid.tv_sec, end->clock_getcpuclockid.tv_nsec, (long long)diff->clock_getcpuclockid.tv_sec, diff->clock_getcpuclockid.tv_nsec, (long long)res->clock_getcpuclockid.tv_sec, res->clock_getcpuclockid.tv_nsec);

    printf("%-27s %15lld.%09ld %15lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld %5lld.%09ld\n", "pthread_getcpuclockid", (long long)start->pthread_getcpuclockid.tv_sec, start->pthread_getcpuclockid.tv_nsec, (long long)end->pthread_getcpuclockid.tv_sec, end->pthread_getcpuclockid.tv_nsec, (long long)diff->pthread_getcpuclockid.tv_sec, diff->pthread_getcpuclockid.tv_nsec, (long long)res->pthread_getcpuclockid.tv_sec, res->pthread_getcpuclockid.tv_nsec);
}

void signal_handler(int sig)
{
    (void)sig;
    /*
        We don't actually need to do anything, just the presence of the
        signal handler is enough to make `clock_nanosleep` return.

        However, because somebody requested that we stop, we *should*
        listen to them and actually stop.
    */
    raise(SIGSTOP);
}

void do_sleep(struct timespec *total)
{
    int not_errno;
    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, '\0', sizeof(act));
    act.sa_handler = signal_handler;
    /* TODO - it is impossible to catch SIGSTOP, is there another way? */
    sigaction(SIGTSTP, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGTTIN, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGTTOU, &act, NULL);
    /*
        Note: synchronous methods of signal handling do *not* work here.
        The `clock_nanosleep` will just resume silently in that case.
        Using `sigtimedwait` does not directly give is a `remain` value.
    */
    do
    {
        /* Important note: clock_nanosleep does *not* use `errno`. */
        not_errno = clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0, total, total);
    }
    while (not_errno == EINTR);
}



static void die(const char *msg)
{
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    exit(1);
}

static void parse_time(char *str, struct timespec *spec)
{
    unsigned long long sec, nsec, multiplier;
    char *end;
    if (!isdigit(str[0]))
    {
        die("Non-numeric character at start of duration.");
    }
    errno = 0;
    sec = strtoull(str, &end, 10);
    spec->tv_sec = sec;
    if (errno || (unsigned long long)spec->tv_sec != sec)
    {
        die("Out-of-range duration.");
    }
    if (*end == '\0')
    {
        spec->tv_nsec = 0;
        return;
    }
    if (*end != '.')
    {
        die("Non-numeric character in duration.");
    }
    ++end;
    multiplier = 100 * 1000 * 1000;
    nsec = 0;
    while (*end)
    {
        unsigned long long digit = *end - '0';
        if (digit >= 10)
        {
            die("Non-numeric character in fractional duration.");
        }
        nsec += multiplier * digit;
        multiplier /= 10;
        ++end;
        /* TODO instead of truncating extra precision, round up? */
    }
    spec->tv_nsec = nsec;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct timespec total;
    struct all_times start, end, diff, res;

    if (argc != 2 || argv[1][0] == '-')
    {
        die("Usage: ./nanosleep sss[.mmmuuunnn]");
    }
    parse_time(argv[1], &total);

    get_all_res(&res);
    get_all_times(&start);
    do_sleep(&total);
    get_all_times(&end);

    diff_all_times(&start, &end, &diff);
    print_all_times(&start, &end, &diff, &res);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./nanosleep 1.2
clock                                       start                     end             diff            res      
CLOCK_REALTIME                   1461281943.302055558      1461281944.502279160     1.200223602     0.000000001
CLOCK_REALTIME                   1461281943.302055558      1461281944.502279160     1.200223602     0.000000001
CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE            1461281943.299600851      1461281944.499668121     1.200067270     0.004000000
CLOCK_MONOTONIC                      130817.112863848          130818.313087604     1.200223756     0.000000001
CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE               130817.110408795          130818.310476065     1.200067270     0.004000000
CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW                  130809.723951252          130810.924108013     1.200156761     0.000000001
CLOCK_BOOTTIME                       198571.683842245          198572.884067547     1.200225302     0.000000001
CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID                  0.002856240               0.002900410     0.000044170     0.000000001
CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID                   0.002857132               0.002903159     0.000046027     0.000000001
clock_getcpuclockid                       0.002857981               0.002905128     0.000047147     0.000000001
pthread_getcpuclockid                     0.002858526               0.002908051     0.000049525     0.000000001
```

Comment: o11c, I could be wrong, but I don't think that's what he wants. I think he just wants to be able to interrupt sleep... see my comment above, where I ask him if he wants the program to sleep 10 sec regardless of pause

Comment: @InnocentBystander when I said that i want the prog to sleep 10 sec regardless of pause, i meant that if ithe sleep run for 5 sec, and then paused, when i send a SIGCONT i want thr sleep to keep "running" for 5 more sec no matter the time that passed

Comment: @Matt.St, OK good. I thought so in the beginning, but got confused by your question. I am glad o11c was able to get you sorted.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I don't know the right solution.
But I have an idea, I hope to help you.

If the code is below

```
{
    ...
    sleep(10);
    ...
}
```

The code maybe will become three part.
sample code as below:

```
{//change code
    ...
    sleep_thread();
    mutex_lock(&sleep_mutex);
    ...
}

{//sleep thread
    mutex_lock(&sleep_mutex);
    sleep(10);
    mutex_unlock(&sleep_mutex);
}

{//handle signal
    if(receive_signal == SIGUSR)
        mutex_unlock(&sleep_mutex);
}
```

Comment: probably use cond_var?

Comment: conditional variable. sorry for my laziness. it is provided by pthread

Comment: No, completely wrong track. `sleep` is never implemented by using threads. Also, you can't call thread-related functions from signal handlers.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try as below, if you enter "ctrl + c":

```
void signal_fun(int singal)
{
    printf("This is signal fun\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    signal(SIGINT, signal_fun);
    sleep(10);
    printf("This is main fun\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: It's not safe to call `printf` in a signal handler.