# Is there any reliable way to detect (after the fact) *when* a SIGSTOP happened?

Tags: c, linux, time

In my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36777637/1405588

I demonstrated how to detect the timing of `SIGTSTP` by letting `clock_nanosleep` be interrupted by a signal handler, which sufficed for that question.

What I want to know is, is there any way to accurately detect the timing of a `SIGSTOP`? Obviously it's possible to detect the *approximate* time by e.g. never sleeping for more than 1 second, but that's not polite.

(I don't actually have a use case for this - usually, receiving any `SIGCONT` means you should go back to your event loop and execute any pending timed event structures, then recalculate the time until the next event).

[`nanosleep(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep) mentions under **BUGS**:

> In Linux 2.4, if nanosleep() is stopped by a signal (e.g., SIGTSTP), then the call fails with the error EINTR after the thread is resumed by a SIGCONT signal. If the system call is subsequently restarted, then the time that the thread spent in the stopped state is not counted against the sleep interval.

which is actually what I'm interested in (and managed to acheive with the signal handler).

Comment: If you want to allow the target process to do arbitrary work before being stopped, then I think you can get pretty close (modulo scheduling delays) by having another suitable process (parent or ptracer) `wait` for it. Or use `systemtap` to monitor signals sent to the process, but that requires superuser access.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick No, after-the-fact detection is enough. And using another process is vulnerable to the monitoring process being stopped.

Comment: Maybe call `setitimer(ITIMER_VIRTUAL , <a very long interval>)` and at the same instant record the wall time. In the SIGCONT handler, call `getitimer`, and see if the time used by the virtual clock is less than the wall clock elapsed time.